# How to know the dependencies of an application in kibana 4?

Tags: dependencies, kibana, packetbeat

I want Dependencies diagram in Kibana.

I'm monitoring an application through ELK. I want the application dependencies in kibana. That application is dependent on which database and which web server. Can i get this information. Please reply immediately if anyone knows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana 4 ships with all of its dependencies wrapped up in a single download. You can find the proper download for your OS here: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana